# I need a help Regarding Proguard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xposed, xposed-framework

Actually I made a Xposed module some day before that time is use Proguard but I see its still easy to read code if someone decompile my apk but I was ok with that but now I am adding license in my app for adding premium feature and now I want to make my all code proper Obfuscate

Comment: On obfuscators you can say that you get what you pay for. The free one I know are more or less useless and the more you pay the better the obfuscation gets. Note that I don't think any of those commercial obfuscators has ever been tested with an Xposed module. This may have unforeseen side-effects.

Comment: Yah thats what i am also thinking but i check some people use a good obfuscators for their module so thats why i want to obfuscators my all code otherwise anyone can read my method for check license and easily manipulate it.

Comment: Nobody forces you to name that method checkLicense. Place an comment on it describing what it does and then refactor the method name to something else.

Comment: Ahh its sound great thanks

Comment: btw you have any idea actually i amworking on a unlocker app for my module that will unlock premium feature on my module and unlocker app will check for license if license success mean app purchased then unlock premium but i dont know how my module mean orginal app know that unlocker app purchased